# How does html5 video tag get duration info from media served by http server?

Tags: video, duration

I want to get the duration info of mp4 files, after searched here, I found there are some tools like MP4Info, ffmpeg which can do that. But seems all these tools need to get the whole media file firstly or they will fail to get the info.

But when I put the video tag into html5 page, seems the browser can correctly get the duration info of corresponding media without the need to download the media file totaly. Here the media was served by http server with range support.

Is there any special method for the html5 video tag implementation to get the metadata info of the media file?

Thanks!

Comment: No, there is nothing “special” – the meta data is just located at the very beginning of the file/stream, so that it can be read first.

Comment: @CBroe I guessed the same way, but when I tried to use tools like ffprobe to get the metadata with part of the file , e.g. 5MB , it failed. And the browser did get the duration while it just only downloaded less than 3MB. what is the problem?

Comment: mp4 files that are being streamed generally have their metadata moved from the end of the file to the start of the file (http://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/) so this may explain what you are seeing. Its also possible that tools like ffprobe will recognise that the video file is incomplete and not give you the info you require.

Comment: mp4 can be divided into 2 parts: moov box, and mdat box. mdat contains the "raw" data for video, audio, subtitles etc. but it is not indexed and is useless without moov box. moov has all kind of information in it (duration, avaliable tracks, how to seek and much more) so basically you have to look inside this moov box to find it out. Like Mick already mentioned moov can be on both ends of file, but each mp4 box has a length field in the header, so you can skip the length of mdat, or use http range requests

Comment: @Mick Thanks! what you said does make sense, I need to learn more knowledge about mp4 file format.

Comment: @incBrain Thanks! Before I saw Mick 's answer , I thought that moov box will be the header of the file.